# Check for null field in arraylist

Tags: java

I can find plenty of Q&A on here about whether an arraylist can equal null, which was helpful in its own way, but I can't find an answer for throwing errors if any fields in the arraylist are null. As I'm adding objects to the arraylist, I want to throw an exception if the user tries to pass in anything that is null. Here is the code:

```
    void addInvoiceItem(Item item, Integer quantity, double discount) throws Exception {    
for (InvoiceItem thing: invoiceList) {
    if (thing == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Part of the invoice item is blank (null). Please review your invoice items and ensure you have specified values for the item.");
    }
    else {
        invoiceList.add(thing);
        thing.setItemQuantity(quantity);
        thing.setItemDiscount(discount);
        System.out.println(invoiceList);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Item class:

```
final class Item {

String itemDescription;
double itemPrice;
Integer itemSKU;

Item (String description, double price, Integer sku) {
    this.itemDescription = description;
    this.itemPrice = price;
    this.itemSKU = sku;
}
```

}

Here are the test methods that are letting me know I'm definitely omitting something. One is to test for a valid InvoiceItem, the other for an invalid one (contains nulls):

```
public class InvoiceTest {
//create the static values to be used
//for InvoiceItem
String goodDescription = "wheel";
double goodPrice = 500.00;
Integer goodSku = 0002;
Item goodInvoiceItem = new Item(goodDescription, goodPrice, goodSku);

String emptyDescription = null;
double emptyPrice = 0;
Integer emptySku = 0;
Item badInvoiceItem = new Item(emptyDescription, emptyPrice, emptySku);

Integer itemQuantity = 0;
double itemDiscount = 0.05;

@Test
public void invalidItemAddTest() {
    Invoice badInvoice = new Invoice(null);
    try {
        badInvoice.addInvoiceItem(badInvoiceItem, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
        System.out.println(badInvoice);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void validItemAddTest() {
    Invoice goodInvoice = new Invoice(null);
    try {
        goodInvoice.addInvoiceItem(goodInvoiceItem, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
        System.out.println(goodInvoice);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Edit with additions:
So Mel's answer was my starting point and I made some additions to get it working the way I needed to. My adding method now looks like this:

```
    void addInvoiceItem(Item item, Integer quantity, double discount) {
    if(item == null || quantity == 0 || discount == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Part of the invoice item is blank (null). Please review your invoice items and ensure you have specified values for the item.");
    } else {
    InvoiceItem invoice = new InvoiceItem(item, quantity, discount);
    invoiceList.add(invoice);
}
}
```

and my test methods look like this:

```
public class InvoiceTest {
//create the static values to be used
//for InvoiceItem
String goodDescription = "wheel";
double goodPrice = 500.00;
int goodSku = 0002;
Item goodInvoiceItem = new Item(goodDescription, goodPrice, goodSku);

String emptyDescription = null;
double emptyPrice = 0;
int emptySku = 0;
Item badInvoiceItem = new Item(emptyDescription, emptyPrice, emptySku);

int badItemQuantity = 0;
double badItemDiscount = 0;
int goodItemQuantity = 1;
double goodItemDiscount = 0.05;


/**
 * @Before - initialize what we need for the test
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() {
    //things needed for testInvalidItemAdd()


}

/**
 * @throws Exception 
 * @Test - confirm you cannot add an item that is null
 */
@Test
public void invalidItemAddTest() {
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    Invoice badInvoice = new Invoice(null);
    try {
        badInvoice.addInvoiceItem(badInvoiceItem, badItemQuantity, badItemDiscount);
        System.out.println(badInvoice);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    assertTrue(exceptionThrown);
}

@Test
public void validItemAddTest() {
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    Invoice goodInvoice = new Invoice(null);
    try {
        goodInvoice.addInvoiceItem(goodInvoiceItem, goodItemQuantity, goodItemDiscount);
        System.out.println(goodInvoice);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    assertFalse(exceptionThrown);
}
```

Comment: Your first code, sounds good.

Comment: um, why are you using `Integer`s? Use `int`s.

Comment: Because I'm a raging noob. Changed to int. I also forgot to mention that I am expecting my invalid test to fail, but it doesn't, which is how I know I'm not doing this right.

Comment: Using an `Integer` does not make you a 'raging noob' if its possible for an item to have no SKU (indicated by null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your add routine is a little off.  It tries to use an item that is already in the list rather than creating a new one.  Try this:

```
void addInvoiceItem(Item item, Integer quantity, double discount) {
    if(
        item == null || 
        quantity == null || 
        item.sku == null ||
        item.description == null
    ) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    InvoiceItem invoice = new InvoiceItem(item, quantity, discount);
    invoiceList.add(invoice);
}
```

Also take a look a checkNotNull( ) from the google library to reduce typing a bit.

It may be useful to check for null in the InvoiceItem constructor rather than in the adder, unless you want to allow nulls elsewhere.

Comment: Just gave this a shot, both my positive and negative tests still pass. I'm very perplexed as to why this is still passing when I expect the exception to get thrown:
 @Test
 public void invalidItemAddTest() {
  Invoice badInvoice = new Invoice(null);
  try {
   badInvoice.addInvoiceItem(badInvoiceItem, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
   System.out.println(badInvoice);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: ugh sorry still figuring out using mini-Markdown for these comments so the code is readable. Comment help says to mark code with 'code'. What exactly does that mean? I've tried enclosing a block with quotes; do I have to mark it line-by-line as code?

Comment: Your tests don't have any asserts in them.  They will always pass.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used asserts to see whether an exception was thrown or not. Do I make that part of the try-catch block or put it outside?

Comment: add a `boolean exceptionThrown = false;` to your test, and set it to `true` inside the catch.  At the end, `assertTrue(exceptionThrown)` if you expected an exception, or assertFalse if you didn't.  Set it the opposite way once as a reality check to see the test fail.

Comment: yes this helps quite a bit, thank you. One last sub question, I have println statements for debugging purposes, but all I see is a nonsense string. I need to do something to make that arraylist object readable for println, but I'm not sure what. Suggestions?

Comment: Also I just realized, my invalid test still technically passes. There is no exception being thrown. The invoice item is still successfully added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20904/discussion-between-city17mogul-and-mel-nicholson)